# Put Jquery object in C# code from .cshtml

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I would like to access the value of `hdnObj` inside the C# code below

```
function refreshGrid() {

        var hdnObj = $("#showInactiveCheckedNotChecked").val();


        @{

            var url = Url.Action("Artifacts", new { controller = "Home", Area = "ArtifactAuthor", inactiveChecked=  });
            var gridUpdate = grid.GetContainerUpdateScript(url);
         }
        @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(gridUpdate.ToHtmlString()));
    };
```

I want `inactiveChecked` equal to the value of `hdnObj`.

From my research, I believe that serializing the JSON object might work. I implemented some code from codeproject.com site but couldn't achieve much.

**Edited:**

I have a hidden field to get if a checkbox is checked or not.

```
<input type="hidden" id="showInactiveCheckedNotChecked" value="false"/>
```

I am passing this value to a controller and refreshing grid based on the checkbox value.

```
public ActionResult Artifacts(DateTime? filterDate,string inactiveChecked)
    {
        if (inactiveChecked =="true")
        {
            IEnumerable<ArtifactDisplayDto> lstAllDocuments = _documentService.GetAllDocumentsForAuthor(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name, filterDate);
            return View(lstAllDocuments);
        }
        IEnumerable<ArtifactDisplayDto> lstActiveDocuments = _documentService.GetAllDocumentsForAuthor(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name, filterDate).Where(u => u.IsActive);
        return View(lstActiveDocuments);

    }
```

That's why I need to assign the value of `hdnObj` to `inactiveChecked`

Just an algorithm,

```
If checkbox checked, 
hdnObj value = true hence, inactiveChecked = true
else 
hdnObj value = false hence, inactiveChecked = false
```

So finally my rephrased question is, how can i pass the hdnObj value to the controller?

Comment: you can't what are you trying to solve ?

Comment: you can't and you dont event need, but we dont know what `GetContainerUpdateScript` do. You need to pass `hdnObj` value as `inactiveChecked` to your `Artifacts` action

Comment: The thing to remember here is the razor part of your view will be evaluated on the *server* whilst the HTML is being rendered.  What is sent to the client will be whatever the result is... and the Javascript code will be executed in the client's browser after it gets the HTML.  So you cannot do what you are asking here.  If you need to dynamically call a controller action from the client, then you need to do the whole thing in JavaScript and not razor

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461313/assign-javascript-variable-to-c-sharp-variable-asp-net Check this out. It's explained very well.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: I have edited the question. Kindly have a look

Comment: @GergelyBakos: Yes precisely. How can I do that? I tried using ajax call but for some reason didn't work.

Comment: @PriyankaDembla  someting like `var url = 'Url.Action("Artifacts", new { controller = "Home", Area = "ArtifactAuthor" })?'+ $("#showInactiveCheckedNotChecked").val()` and you call that url from ajax.